# Chord of a parabola $y^{2}= 4ax$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Prove that on the axis of any parabola
$y^2=4ax$
there is a certain point $K$ which has the property that,if a chord $PQ$ of the parabola be drawn through it ,then
$$\frac{1}{PK^2}+\frac{1}{QK^2}$$
is same for all positions of the chord.Find also the coordinates of the point $K$.

We can apply the parametric equations of a parabola
Let the points $P$ and $Q$ be
$(at_1^{2},2at_1)$ and $(at_2^{2}, 2at_2)$

So the equation of the chord would be
$$y(t_1+t_2)=2x+2at_1t_2$$

Hence from there we have that the coordinates of $K$ are
$(−at_1t_2,0)$

Now our aim is to show that
$\frac{1}{PK^2}+\frac{1}{QK^2}$
is independent of
$t_1$ and $t_2$. I tried and applied the distance formula but no benefit.

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  please help

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** This is **beyond** easy ! :-$)$ The sum in question stays constant, **regardless** of the position of *P*, correct ? So just let $K=(b,0),$ and then take two positions for *P*: when *P* is right above $($or right below$)$ *K*, and when $P\to\infty$. Where is *Q* in both these cases ? Can you deduce the value of *b* from equating the two sums ? I just did, and used [GeoGebra](http://app.geogebra.org/#algebra) to verify the result.

Comment: Can you elaboate it please .

Comment: Can you tell me some other way please!!!!!!

Comment: @user101522: Were you at the very least able to determine the position of *Q* $($and the lengths of the two segments$)$ in each of the two cases I mentioned ?